# Google Analytics API v4 for Android App Crash at Start

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I've set all things for google analytics api v4 as it mentioned here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/
and here: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/04/working-with-google-analytics-api-v4-for-android.html

i done all steps.

I run my app but is crashing

Here is my **global_tracker.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <!-- The apps Analytics Tracking Id -->
    <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXXX-15</string>

    <!-- Percentage of events to include in reports -->
    <string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

    <!-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

    <!-- catch and report uncaught exceptions from the app -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

    <!-- How long a session exists before giving up -->
    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">-1</integer>

    <!-- If ga_autoActivityTracking is enabled, an alternate screen name can be specified to substitute for the full length canonical Activity name in screen view hit. In order to specify an alternate screen name use an <screenName> element, with the name attribute specifying the canonical name, and the value the alias to use instead. -->
    <screenName name="com.example.test.MainActivity">MainActivity</screenName>
</resources>
```

Here is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />



    <application
        android:name=".Global"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.test.MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SelectedImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <!-- Google Analytics Version v4 needs this value for easy tracking -->
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
            android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my **AnalyticsApplication.java**

```
 public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER,
    GLOBAL_TRACKER,
    E_COMMERCE_TRACKER,
}
HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();
synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        Tracker t = null;
        if(trackerId==TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER){
            t= analytics.newTracker("UA-66XXXXX-1");
        }
        mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
}
```

}

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        //Get a Tracker (should auto-report) 2
        Tracker tracker = ((AnalyticsApplication) getApplication()).getTracker(AnalyticsApplication.TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER);
        tracker.setScreenName("MainActivity");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }
```

My **Build Gradle** :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Build Gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile files('libs/main.jar')

     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.commit451:NativeStackBlur:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
  }
```

My **Logcate** :

```
01-10 22:29:13.627  11614-11620/? E/jdwp﹕ Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
01-10 22:29:13.791  11614-11614/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.test.Global cannot be cast to com.example.test.AnalyticsApplication
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.test.Global cannot be cast to com.example.test.AnalyticsApplication
            at com.example.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest you have reported:

```
<application 
    android:name=".Global"
```

Basing on your stack trace, `AnalyticsApplication` is you `Application` class, so it should be:

```
<application 
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
```

Comment: @OtmanElOuah which error message do you see now in stack trace?

Comment: App Crached again, i see error MainActivity          tracker.setScreenName("MainActivity");

Comment: @OtmanElOuah Ok, so it means your original question is answered and the answer should be accepted, since crash you reported doesn't occur anymore. If you have another question, feel free to ask another one.